# Inequalities proven by real analysis or induction.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $t\in [-1,1]$. Prove that $(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p\ge2$ when $p\ge 1$ and that $(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p \le 2$ where $0 \le p\le 1$.

I am not sure how I should solve it. I tried induction at first and it was pretty well, but induction is for natural numbers I believe, and besides, it has no use in the next, dense case. I tried build a function with respect to "$p$" which was intricate. I am lost... Would appreciate your help...

Answer (score 4):

Direct application of [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliInequality.html) perhaps,

For $p \ge 1$ and $t \in (-1,1)$,

$$(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p > 1+pt + 1-pt = 2$$

and the reverse for $p < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** for $p > 1$ we use [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) and get: $$(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p \geq 1+tp+1-tp = 2.$$
Look at $p = 0$ and $p=1$ separately. If $0<p<1$, then $1/p > 1$ and think in the same fashion.

Comment: ugh! I didn't see you answered before me. (+1) I can delete mine if you want ..

Comment: Our answers are a lot different, I pointed out that $1/p > 1$ and you pointed that the inequality already reverses for $p < 1$. (!!!) There is no need to delete it :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$((1+x)^p)''=p(p-1)(1+x)^{p-2}$$
which means $(1+x)^p$ is convex for $p\ge 1$ and concave for $0\le p\le 1$. Therefore by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form)
$$\frac{(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p}2\ge 1^p=1\text{ if }p\ge1\ \text{ and }\ \frac{(1+t)^p+(1-t)^p}2\le 1^p=1\text{ if }0\le p\le1$$

Comment: (+1) hah! I was editing in power mean in my answer :-) guess that's unecessary now :D Nice !!!!

Comment: Creative, really!